Why might Spring Boot 3 logging file not be created?
In a Spring Boot application recently updated from Boot 2.5 to 3.2.4. We've always used the config property logging.file.name to specify where log files are created, never had any problem. Since the update to Boot 3, however, we are no longer getting log files created.
We use YAML for externalized configuration, and I've tried all of the following without success:
logging:
  file:
    name: logs/my-app-log.txt

logging:
  file:
   path: logs

-Dlogging.file.name=appLog.txt passed on the command line that starts the application.
Regardless of what I try, I never get a log file created, only console logging.
We do not have any custom logback-spring.xml or other logging impl config files.
Just to be sure, I double-checked the documentation to confirm that these properties are (still) the correct names - they are. I also confirmed that no file system permissions have changed and the user account running the app can write to the folders.
What other reasons can there be for not getting log files created?

By setting the system property logback.debug to true (I passed -Dlogback.debug=true on the command-line that starts my app) I was able to see that Logback was finding a logback.xml config file on the classpath. It was embedded in a dependency I have, which is a big no-no for publishing libraries.
That logback.xml file did not include a file appender, which is why log files for my application were not being created - the presence of logback.xml on the classpath is part of Logback's configuration discovery mechanism and causes Spring Boot's own default configuration to be bypassed.
One workaround would be to create my own logback.xml file in my app's src/main/resources folder (if using Gradle or Maven) and fully configure Logback there.
Luckily for me the existence of logback.xml in that dependency was already reported as a bug and fixed in a new release; updating my dependency to the new release resolved the issue.
